# How to copy and paste sample ID to end of header

Tags: sed

I have a fasta file with headers that look like...

```
>DNA1111_0

>DNA2987_1

>DNA3674_5
```

How do I used sed to modify the headers so they look like...

```
>DNA1111_0;sample=DNA1111

>DNA2987_1;sample=DNA2987

>DNA3674_5;sample=DNA3674
```

I haven't been able to get the correct modification, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^>(.*)(_.*)$/>\1\2;sample=\1/' file
```

Output:

```
>DNA1111_0;sample=DNA1111

>DNA2987_1;sample=DNA2987

>DNA3674_5;sample=DNA3674
```

Answer (score 0):

With any sed that supports `-E` (e.g. GNU and OSX seds):

```
$ sed -E 's/([^>_]+).*/&;sample=\1/' file
>DNA1111_0;sample=DNA1111

>DNA2987_1;sample=DNA2987

>DNA3674_5;sample=DNA3674
```